# Me muestra error en registrar usuario en mi jsp

Tags: java, oracle, servlets

Estoy haciendo un registrar usuario, pero al registrarlo me envía al servlet y me muestra una pagina en blanco.

Estoy con oracle, ya revise la conexión con la db y esta bien.

aquí esta el código del servlet que debe hacer el registro:

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("alertaRegistro", false);
        Usuario usu = new Usuario();
        UsuarioDAO usudao = new UsuarioDAO();
        Cliente cli = new Cliente();
        ClienteDAO clidao = new ClienteDAO();
        
        String m_alert = "";
        String razon_social = request.getParameter("razon_social");
        String rut_empresa = request.getParameter("rut_empresa");
        String nom_rep_legal = request.getParameter("nom_rep_legal");
        String rut_rep_legal = request.getParameter("rut_rep_legal");
        String nombre_usuario = request.getParameter("nombre_usuario");
        String contrasena = request.getParameter("contrasena");
        String rep_contrasena = request.getParameter("rep_contrasena");
        String telefono = request.getParameter("telefono");
        String correo_electronico = request.getParameter("correo_electronico");
        String rep_correo_elec = request.getParameter("rep_correo_elec");
        String direccion = request.getParameter("direccion");;
        String region = request.getParameter("region");
        String provincia = request.getParameter("provincia");
        String comuna = request.getParameter("comuna");
        String direccionCompleta;
        
        int estadoInsertCliente;

                if (estadoInsertCliente == 1) {
                    Usuario usu2 = usudao.obtenerDatosUsuario(usu.getCorreo_electronico(), usu.getContrasena());
                    request.setAttribute("nombre_usuario", usu2.getNombre_usuario());
                    request.setAttribute("contrasena", usu2.getContrasena());
                    request.setAttribute("razon_social", usu2.getRazon_social());
                    request.setAttribute("registrado", estadoInsertCliente);
                    request.setAttribute("correo_registro", usu2.getCorreo_electronico());
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("vistas/registro_exitoso.jsp").forward(request, response);
                } else {
                    
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("vistas/error_registro.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

no logro determinar cual es el error en el codigo.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: @Nilvia te recomiendo que te veas un tutorial de como hacer debugg: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-debugging.htm

Comment: otro punto es que el código que compartiste tiene errores de sintaxis con los brackets ... seria posible que nos envíes un ejemplo de tu tabla (estructura) y del código (recomiendo que uses variables declaradas en lugar de las pasadas al método ) para que podamos ayudarte, saludo.

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, debes mostrar el trace que ves de tu log del servidor que estés ejecutando. (ya sea apache, wildfly, glassfish, etc) con eso fácilmente se encuentra donde esta el error.